# Does animal soul (Nefesh) come from the divine or the material?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, animals, parashat-bereishit, creation, soul

[I assume] it is wildly accepted in Judaism that animals have souls (hence "anima"). In Hebrew, it is called נפש (Nefesh) and the Torah is full of this kind of references:

> "וּֽלְכׇל־חַיַּ֣ת הָ֠אָרֶץ וּלְכׇל־עֹ֨וף הַשָּׁמַ֜יִם וּלְכֹ֣ל רֹומֵ֣שׂ עַל־הָאָ֗רֶץ אֲשֶׁר־בֹּו֙ נֶ֣פֶשׁ חַיָּ֔ה אֶת־כׇּל־יֶ֥רֶק עֵ֖שֶׂב לְאׇכְלָ֑ה וַֽיְהִי־כֵֽן׃"
> "וְכֹל֩ אֲשֶׁ֨ר יִקְרָא־לֹ֧ו הָֽאָדָ֛ם נֶ֥פֶשׁ חַיָּ֖ה ה֥וּא שְׁמֹֽו׃", etc

The process of the creation of Adam is clearly two-fold: the creation of the material body and the infusion of the soul:

> "וַיִּיצֶר֩ ה"א אֶת־הָֽאָדָ֗ם עָפָר֙ מִן־הָ֣אֲדָמָ֔ה
> וַיִּפַּ֥ח בְּאַפָּ֖יו נִשְׁמַ֣ת חַיִּ֑ים
> **וַֽיְהִ֥י הָֽאָדָ֖ם לְנֶ֥פֶשׁ חַיָּֽה׃**"

We are all familiar with the notion that the human soul is "חלק אלוק ממעל" (a part of the divine) (Job 31,2). However, contrary to the Man, the infusion of [any type of] soul is not mentioned with the animals:

> "וַיִּצֶר ה"א מִן־הָאֲדָמָה כָּל־חַיַּת הַשָּׂדֶה וְאֵת כָּל־עוֹף הַשָּׁמַיִם..."

My question is: where does the animal soul (Nefesh), which comprises the instincts, social and intelligent behaviors, come from - from the divine, in the process omitted in the Torah, or from the material, as described, being its integral "feature"?

Comment: From the same place as the animal soul of the Jew

Comment: If we go with the literal meanings of Nefesh and Neshama (throat and breath) then it makes sense the Nefesh wouldn't be blown in but be formed from physical substance.

Comment: Man also had its נפש when it was made, before the neshama was blown in. Why not ask about man?

Comment: Aristotle said that man's intelligence separates him from animals. The animals probably got their souls when they were made or conceptualized in the womb, like humans babies today.

Comment: @robev is right. Adam existed before he had the neshama. Additionally, Adam had a father and a mother like you and me.